# Can't update Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I've tried using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but it says that the apt-transport-https isn't installed.

Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

but it tells me to do sudo apt-get update.

Then I try to do

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

but it says that the packages have unmet dependencies:

apt-transport-https : Depends: libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 1.0.9.8.5) but 1.0.9.8.2 is installed

I try using

```
sudo apt full-upgrade -f
```

but error 404 occurs for every file